# Web page like application hosted on Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

We are trying to create a web page which will have a form with paginations.First page will
seek for Clients' information and the next page will request them to upload the documentations.Once submitted, it will create a case in Salesforce and insert all the documents uploaded.It should also show the clients the Case number which was created.

Once the documents are verified in Salesforce by Agents,It will update the status of those Documents on a new WebPage (with green tick or red tick), where Clients can go and check the status of their documents based on Case number that was provided to them.

Now I know this can be achieved by Salesforce Sites, but we are on lightning and don't want to dabble with VF pages. Also I am not sure how well this will scale since we have a huge client base who might visit the page.Can we somehow use LWC?

Please help me with an optimum design.

Comment: why not use lighting communities?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Lightning communities to present users with a page that does exactly what you describe, however, there are licensing costs involved.

As per using VF/sites to host an SPA, you can refer [Creating Lightning Components: Single Page Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/04/creating-lightning-components-1.html) for considerations.

It is worth noting that you don't need Salesforce to host an SPA that does what you have described, you can create a SPA using [LWC OSS](https://lwc.dev/) and host the app on [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) or AWS, or any other platform out there and leverage the [Record UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_ui.htm).

for more on Licensing, please refer to [Experience Cloud User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a lil on licenses? We don’t want any users we just want clients to visit the site and insert the case.

Comment: added a link for reference purposes

Comment: Thanks glls . We do have Azure ,will find similar service to host a web app on it or may be Heroku.I will explore Experience cloud as well.

Comment: if you are using azure, i would suggest you stick to azure, you can deploy a container using docker and azures container service/registry or simply using azure web app service

Comment: the only gotcha is managing the authentication, however, this should be trivial

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flows and expose them through Lightning Community. For the screen elements in the flow you can use custom Lightning Components.

We have used this design and works very well.

Comment: Thanks Rajiv , the solution seems viable!